# Are there Bibles with each JEDP source set aside separately?

Tags: hebrew-bible, torah, documentary-hypothesis

Are there any editions or translations of the Bible which set aside each source (J, E, P etc.) separately? I am aware that there is a 'Book of J', the oldest text, I'm just wondering if there are any versions of the Tanakh (or at least the Torah) which separate each source to read independently. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a text that has the traditional bible structure but with JEDP sources annotated/marked, or a text that has the JEDP sources and the traditional structure annotated.  There may not be a big market for something that can't also be read as a regular bible, but for example Logos software allows you to query JEDP sources according to one hypothesis. There is also disagreement as to what goes in each JEDP component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a book which shows the Torah with the JEPD breakdown throughout. The Bible with Sources Revealed Paperback – Illustrated, August 16, 2005.  By Richard Elliott Friedman

Comment: This was also suggested in an answer that was given and then deleted by the author over 3 years ago. It contains these potentially useful warnings: "*Almost downloaded the Kindle version, but saw the note that the color-coding doesn't work on b/w Kindle.*", and "*Unfortunately, Hebrew is missing.*".